# Conda update failing - I can't satisfy my python either

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update all my python libraries, but I keep getting an error (below). I've removed and updated these libraries, but continue to get the error. I'd like to understand what it is telling me and how to figure this out myself if it happens again.

```
C:\>conda update --all --alt-hint Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications:
................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
.................................................... 
Error:
Unsatisfiable package specifications. Generating minimal hint: [     
COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%

The following set of clauses is unsatisfiable:

hdf5-1.8.15.1-vc10_3 zlib-1.2.8-vc10_2 => not zlib-1.2.8-vc9_2
zlib-1.2.8-vc10_2 hdf5-1.8.15.1-vc10_3 => zlib-1.2.8-vc9_2
```

Comment: I've removed both hdf5 and zlib and reinstalled both of them. this did not resolve the error.

Comment: Just update the package you actually want to update and conda will automatically update any requirements, if needed.

Comment: I assume without `--alt-hint` gives a similar error?

Comment: yes, w/o --alt hint, I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/advanced-features-conda-part-1:

Section `conda update --all`:

> A common problem is that if you want to update package versions past the versions specified in the anaconda metapackage, you will need to remove it with conda remove anaconda. (This will only remove the metapackage, which doesn’t contain any code.)
>
> The anaconda metapackage is designed for people who want to keep a stable set of packages, which have been tested together. It is updated every few months. If you want to do this, you should keep anaconda installed and use conda update anaconda to update things. If you want to update packages individually to the latest versions as they come out, you should conda remove anaconda and use conda update --all to keep packages up-to-date.

I faced the same problem as you. My solution was to remove both packages (hdf5 and zlib), since I did't need them. If you do need them, you can either stick to package version that come with anaconda (so no updating at all) or only update the packages you really need to have updated.

Comment: I removed anaconda a while back and the update --all has worked for months. I can (and have) updated all the packages one-by-one manually. Still, I'm trying to understand what it is telling me so that when it happens again, I can fix it.